# Class Objects - Hierachy and Inheritance ( NOT WORKING)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a (People) or Users objects, of which I am using class inheritance to create the various objects.

However I am getting errors INVALID COLUMN, when I add the object, Users_Accounts which exist in the database with their respective columns below, I get the error

what am I doing wrong ?

ERROR MESSAGE
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Invalid column name 'Users_AccountsAccountID'.
Invalid column name 'Users_AccountsAccountID'.
Invalid column name 'Users_PhonePhoneID'.

```
namespace Accounts.i_EF.Accounts
{
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dates { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuspended { get; set; }


     public Users_Accounts Users_Accounts { get; set; }


}
public class Users_Accounts
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public string UniqueID { get; set; }
    public Title Title { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public Users_Phone Users_Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime  Dates { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuspended { get; set; }
}
public enum Gender
{
    male,female

}
```

and my controller code

```
 var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        var DataContext = _context.Users.Include(c => c.Users_Accounts);


return View(await DataContext.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Email == user && !c.IsSuspended));
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the two models ? One-to-one ? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
namespace Accounts.i_EF.Accounts
    {
    public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Guid UniqueID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dates { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuspended { get; set; }
        public int UserAccountID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserAccountID))]
        public Users_Accounts Users_Accounts { get; set; }


    }
    public class Users_Accounts
    {
        [Key]
        public int AccountID { get; set; }
        public string UniqueID { get; set; }
        public Title Title { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public int UserPhoneID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserPhoneID))]
        public Users_Phone Users_Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public DateTime  Dates { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuspended { get; set; }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserID ))]
        public Users Users { get; set; }
    }
    public enum Gender
    {
        male,female

    }
```

Comment: does not work. I even tried using [ForeignKey("UserID ")]